# "... or not" translated as "ou non" or "ou pas"

Tags: traduction, négation

> We will see whether it rains or not.
>
> Nous allons voir s'il pleut ___

Should the "or not" part be translated as "ou non" or "ou pas"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can be used, *ou non* is more literary.